# like ...Gerund or other form?

Tags: gerunds, ing

"There are many ways to save the environment, like saving energy, reducing rubbish" 
Is the ing Form correct in this case?
Is it a gerund? Or is this Form calles differently ?

Comment: Your examples are fine. "Saving" and "reducing" are gerund-participle verbs heading the gerund-participial clauses "saving energy". and "reducing rubbish". "Energy" and "rubbish" are the direct objects of the clauses.

Comment: *Saving energy **is** one of the ways to save the environment*. Since the first word (or two) serve as a *subject* there, it's obviously functioning as a noun (effectively, the definition of a gerund is it's a verb functioning as a noun).

Comment: @FumbleFingers That’s a bit too imprecise for my tastes, since now you've made there be a “gerund” in *To live well is hard*. A gerund is a verb inflected into its *-ing* form and heading a verb phrase where that verb phrase  happens to be standing in for a noun phrase in the larger clause. The gerund does not "function as a noun" because it still does only verb things like objects and adverbs not noun things like adjectives and prepositions. But the gerund clause can serve as a noun clause, which is different.

Comment: Being the subject or indirect object of a clause is very much a noun thing. So is taking a possessive if you're still into that. _His moving to Malaga was a mistake._

Comment: @KarlG No, it's a **noun phrase** thing.  In the prepositional phrase *“like saving energy”*, the word *saving* is clearly a verb because its object is *energy*. It is the verb-phase *saving energy* that is serving as the object of the preposition. When an *-ing* verb phrase is doing the job of a noun phrase like this, we call that *-ing* verb a gerund. But it is not being a noun in any regard; it is only, ever, and always a verb.

Comment: You will have to explain to me the difference between _functioning as a noun_, to which you object, and _doing the job of a noun_.

Comment: @tchrist In the phrase "When the going gets tough", the word "going" is acting as the subject of the verb "gets", and is taking the adjective "tough". So is it your position that there's a noun phrase consisting solely of the word "going" that is distinct from the word "going"?

Comment: @KarlG The difference is that you're confusing the phrase for the thing, a syntactic constituent for a part of speech. "saving energy" has only one noun: *energy*. It is a verb phrase with an *-ing* verb and its object. The word *saving* is a verb, not a noun. It is not "functioning as a noun". It is not "doing the job of a noun". It is a verb doing the job of a verb: heading a verb phrase.

Comment: @Acccumulation No, that one seem to be a noun, because if you try to do verby things to it it doesn't sound too good: *When the going *quickly and quietly gets tough...*

Comment: It could still be argued that 'the going' is that which functions as a noun, not just 'going' itself.

Comment: @NigelJ Yes, you're right about that, but I would say "functions as a noun phrase". The thing is that gerund phrases can take determiners: “His constantly calling home bothered her.“*

Comment: @tchrist Would you agree that a gerund is a 'doing thing' but a noun is just a 'thing' ?

Comment: @NigelJ Oh, I don't know: I've never thought about it that way. I tend not to believe in applying Latin grammar to English. The currently popular *gerund-participle* term of art, while an improvement, is still something of a compromise. We have two kinds of non-finite verb phrases in English that can both alternately function as substantives or as modifiers: the infinitive phrase and the gerund-particple phrase. The heads of those phrases are still just verbs, but that verb phrase will be used where either a noun phrase or a modifier phrase is called for. It's still not a noun. :)

Comment: @tchrist: I'm not confusing anything. I'm merely pointing out that there is no essential difference between _functioning as a noun [phrase]_ and _doing the job of a noun phrase_ and that using the former will still preserve the ontology of The Verb unsullied by nounness.

Answer (score 1):

In a comment, BillJ wrote:

> Your examples are fine. "Saving" and "reducing" are gerund-participle verbs heading the gerund-participial clauses "saving energy". and "reducing rubbish". "Energy" and "rubbish" are the direct objects of the clauses.